Множественное или единственное число глагола? (2)
Скажите, как правильно написать?
Возможностей пусть будут(ет) миллиарды.
Мне кажется, что логичнее множественное число, но будто привычнее звучит в единственном числе.

Добрый вечер, Олеся! К вам серьезный вопрос: а почему вы не отмечаете полезность вопросов, то есть не голосуете? На сегодня — у вас 25 вопросов и только один голос. Странно, честное слово.

Римма Михайловна, добрый день! Где необходимо проголосовать? Все сделаю)

Олеся, в каждом ответе есть не только галочка (отметьте этот ответ как принятый, если он решает вашу проблему или был наиболее полезен при поиске решения), но и верхний кружочек с  треугольником (ответ полезен). Отмечая понравившийся вам ответ (а они все могут быть такими), вы поддерживаете отвечающего 10 баллами репутации, стимулируете его. И мы понимаем, что вы цените его мнение, его труд.

• Для начала правило из "Справочника по правописанию, произношению, литературному редактированию" (§184. Сказуемое при подлежащем — количественно-именном сочетании (счетном обороте)):

7. При словах тысяча, миллион, миллиард сказуемое обычно согласуется по правилам согласования с подлежащими-существительными (в роде и числе), например: Тысяча книг поступила в школьную библиотеку; Миллион демонстрантов заполнил площади и улицы столицы.

• Затем немного информации о порядоке слов в предложении.
• Теперь ответ
"Миллиарды возможностей" — это счётный оборот.
Правильно использовать множественное число глагола (сказуемого):
Возможностей пусть будут миллиарды.
В предложении использована инверсия (см. в ссылке).
Без нее предложение выглядело бы так: Пусть будут миллиарды возможностей.
Если используется единственное числа глагола, то предложения должны быть такими:
Возможностей пусть будет миллиард (с инверсией).
Пусть будет миллиард возможностей (при прямом порядке).
• Примеры
Избавьтесь от них, и перед вами откроются миллионы возможностей! (О. Дуплякина).
У нас существуют миллионы возможностей выбора того, как думать (М. Гало).
